# Auto layout not fit for UITextfiled in iphone6

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

This is my first try in AutoLayout, I dont know what is the error

When I run on iPhone 5, it shows like
[image: first image]

And when I run on iPhone 6, it shows like

[image: second image]

Why it is expanding button height as well as UITextField width.
I'm learning auto layout for project work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well.... it is doing that because your constraints are set that way. Your constraints are wrong. I guess you used the auto-create missing constraints? It sucks in all but the most trivial cases. You need to manually apply your constraints to have control.

Comment: You have missed to add bottom constraint of View. You can add this from AutoLayout icons available on bottom right corner of StoryBoard View.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey i given bottom constraint from bottom layout guide

Comment: @Spoek you are correct,i have used auto correct missing constraints

Comment: @karthikeyan then you shouldn't expect it to "know" what you want. Start over with a view with less UI-elements, and learn that way. Never use auto correct missing constraints if you want to learn how constraints work. I recommend ctrl-dragging from a UI-element to another, to have full control.

Comment: @karthikeyan What? I gave you a suggestion: ctrl-drag between your components to pick constraints with care. I have no idea what is wrong with your constraints without seeing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you probably have pinned the top, left, right and bottom edge of the third row button to its immediate neighbor's  edges. 
Elaborately, the two buttons'-

1. top edge may have been pinned with the bottom edge of the segmented control, and
2. the bottom, left and right edge may have been pinned with the ViewController's bottom, left and right edge.

That's why when the height of the screen extends, the buttons assume that they need to extend their heights too.

Solution:

First figure out what you want. you have two options-

a.You may want to place your button at a constant distance from your segmented control or

b. You may want to place the button towards the bottom edge of your screen.

**Option a:**

Don't pin the bottom edge of the button to its Parent view's(the grey view's) bottom, otherwise it will extend with the height of the screen. So, just set its top to the segmented control's bottom, so that your button always know at what distance, it needs to be, and also specify its width and height.

[image]

**Option b:**

Pin the bottom edge of the button to its Parent view's(the grey view's) bottom. In this case, don't set the top space to the segmented control. This way, your button will always know that it needs to stay towards the bottom. Also in this case, you need to specify your button's height and width

[image]
Lastly as the screen's width increased, the textfield's width also increased. Probably, you set the left and right edge of the textfield to the view controller's left and right edge which is good. You just need to set the left and right edge of your Grey view the same way as of the text field.

One Advice: Always make sure that your element/view knows how to calculate its size and starting or ending position, and specify that with as less constrains as possible because the more constrains you put, the getter the chance of conflicts.

I hope, this helps.